# GLKit GLKVertexAttribColor: Dynamically changing colours

Tags: ios, opengl-es, glkit, eaglview, texturing

So As objects get further away from me I want to apply a fade.
The objects are textured.

I believe the colour of the object is controlled via this line

```
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribColor, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (const GLvoid *) offsetof(Vertex, Color));
```

Instead of the colour being taken from the Vertex array, is there away to insert a colour in to this?

I have tried setting glColor4 etc and setting

```
effect.useConstantColor = YES;
effect.constantColor =  self.color;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to do this is to use fog.  Check out the docs for the [GLKBaseEffect fog property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GLkit/Reference/GLKEffectPropertyFog_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/GLKEffectPropertyFog)

Comment: This would probably be easiest; another option is if you're using GLSL is to calculate the eye distance (transpose vertex from model->world->eye) and then darken the vertex color accordingly.